# Sampling two normal distribution "in the same way"

Tags: python, numpy, random, sampling

Suppose I want to sample a normal distribution. This is straightforward through `rng = numpy.random.default_rng()` and then `rng.normal(mean, std, size)`.
This is also easy if I want to change the standard deviation, like `rng.normal(mean, std*2, size)`.

However, executing the two commands give "different" result. To my understanding, on of the possible way in which sampling may happen is via inverse transform: so it is like I am choosing a random value `r` from an uniform distribution and using it to index the inverse of the cumulative distribution of the normal distribution, like `F_X^(-1)(r)`. Now, I think that if I use `rng.normal(mean, std, size)` and `rng.normal(mean, std*2, size)` each of them will produce `size = (a,b,c) -> a+b+c` samples which will NOT correspond to the same sample from the uniform distribution (i.e., they will use different values of `r`). **This is not how it is implemented in numpy**, but I think that the actual sample that I would obtain will be different in this sense (based on the actual implementation [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f1e50253a3b56375e795ee72032cca90a3832cd4/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c#L137), it is like I am using a different state, but I am not sure).

In other words, I am searching a method that will provide me a sample from `rng.normal(mean, std, size)` and the sample obtained in the same way but using `rng.normal(mean, 2*std, size)`, so a different standard deviation.

I thougt about manipulating the sample produced by `rng.normal(mean, std, size)` in order to obtain the desired result:

```
def alter_value(value, new_std, prev_mean=0, prev_std=1):
    # use the PDF expression to obtain p(x)
    gaussian_value = 1/(np.sqrt(2)*prev_std) * np.exp(-(value-prev_mean)**2/2/prev_std**2)
    # fixed p(x), obtain the new x
    new_x = prev_mean - np.log(np.sqrt(2)*new_std*gaussian_val)*2*new_std**2
    return new_x
```

However, I do not know if this is the correct method at all.

Comment: *"To my understanding, sampling in numpy happens via inverse transform..."*  Actually it does not, at least not for the normal distribution.  The code that generates samples from the standard normal distribution starts here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f1e50253a3b56375e795ee72032cca90a3832cd4/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c#L137

Comment: What if you reset the random seed to the same value before sampling each distribution?

Comment: As @slothrop suggests, reset the seed between calls.  E.g. `rng = np.random.default_rng(0x1ce1cebab1e); sample0 = rng.normal(size=4)`, and then `rng = np.random.default_rng(0x1ce1cebab1e); sample1 = rng.normal(loc=1, scale=2, size=4)`.  Then `sample1` will be the same as `1 + 2*sample0`.

Comment: @slothrop I thought about that, but how can I confirm that this is the right way to proceed? I mean, I verified that doing something like `rng = np.random.default_rng(2)` before sampling yield the same result, but will it be the same in the sense I have stated in the post?

Comment: @King Powa: you can get the `r` values corresponding to your drawn values by doing `rs = scipy.stats.norm(loc=loc, scale=scale).cdf(drawn_values)` where `loc` and `scale` are the mean and stdev that you passed to `rng.normal`.  The same choice of seed will give the same result here, regardless of the values of `loc` and `scale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get *repeatable* or closely-analogous random samples is to set the "seed" or "state" of the random number generator [directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.setstate). The result isn't guaranteed to obey your `alter_value()` function, but as long as you always set the state to the same value before calling your function, and as long as you don't change the function itself, the output of the RNG is guaranteed to be the same. (See also comments from @slothrop and @warren-weckesser on your question.)

This *probably* works because under the hood, numpy is likely just drawing random numbers and scaling them based on the standard deviation & mean - the way your `alter_value()` does. It's possible for numpy to do something more complex but there's no reason for it to do so.

A "RNG" is just a fixed "pseudorandom" sequence of numbers, so as long as that sequence is being consumed in the same way, starting at the same position will yield the same sequence every time.

Of course, if you absolutely need the behavior of `alter_value()` just use that function... but if you just want to be able to reproduce the behavior at a high level, setting the seed will do it.

Comment: I have confirmed that this indeed produced the same result I seek. Thank you for the clarification.